# How do I turn on/off the d7000 view finder / monitor?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000

I am having trouble figuring out how to turn on the view finder display/ monitor on my d7000. the instructions are of no help and the web is no better.

I am fearing that the unit may be defective cause i have pressed all the buttons on the darn thing already and nothing.

Comment: Sorry but this question does not mean much. The viewfinder and display are completely different things. You do not need to turn on the viewfinder and the display will turn on as needed when you use the camera. Pressing the info button while also cycle through various display modes, showing you different things until you see what you are looking for.

Comment: prior to viting down try helping. anyway thanks to rfuska !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're talking about the video screen on the back for live view, I believe the D7000 has the little spring loaded toggle switch.  Its a small switch with a red dot button in the middle of it, towards the upper right hand corner of the screen.  Rotate it clockwise.

See the picture below with the "Lv" and the red dot on the button.  Rotate that lever.
[image]

Comment: wow, perfect. thats did it. i know i tried that earlier but the screen didint show anything... oh well, i got it now. thanks

Comment: @kacalapy - If that worked, it probably appropriate to mark this as accepted then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the manual shutter release plugged in and could not turn on my video screen in the back. I unplugged the cable and it worked. I guess this is normal for the D7000.